# Why would btfss fail sometimes on PIC12f1822

Tags: pic, voltage

I have a PIC12f1822 in a simple circuit, running very simple code. In a critical loop in the code, a BTFSS instruction mis-reads the port pin. This happens about 1% of the time.

To a first approximation, the code is simply copying the state of pin 4 to either pin 2 or 3, depending on the state of pin 5. The PIC is supplied with regulated 5v. Strangely, this problem only seems to manifest if I use 0v-5v input signals. If I use 0v-3.3v inputs, the problem seems to go away.

Is there any strange electrical property of a PIC which can make it miss read a port pin 1% of the time?

[image: Simple PIC12F1822 circuit]
[image: 1us spikes]

```
MAIN_LOOP

    btfsc   CS_INPUT            
    goto    MAIN_LOOP

    movlw   B'00010000'
    btfsc   INDF0, 2            ; INDF0 points to PORTA
    movlw   B'00100000'         
    movwf   INDF1               ; INDF1 points to LATA

    movlw   B'00110000'

WAIT_CS_HIGH
    btfss   CS_INPUT            ; This test fails sometimes
    goto    WAIT_CS_HIGH

    movwf   INDF1


    GOTO MAIN_LOOP

    END
```

Comment: GPO, GP1 set to input or output. Grounded with resistor or floating?

Comment: They were originally floating inputs, so I tried grounding them. But it made no difference.

Comment: Have you tried this with another PIC of the same series? Maybe there's a problem with that particular unit.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to because we were out of stock. There should be more coming tomorrow. I'll let you know.

Comment: Silly question, but how are you measuring it? That looks like a purely digital logic analyzer output. Maybe you have some noise there.

Comment: @darron: I have checked it on a proper analogue scope and the waveform looks the same. However, it's easier to do a screen grab from the logic analyser software.

Answer (score 3):

The BTFSS instruction isn't just going to fail randomly.  You're not going to find what is wrong with your circuit or code until you stop trying to blame the PIC.  There is something wrong with *your* setup.

First I would simplify the code.  Going thru INDF registers to access ports adds another layer of stuff to go wrong.  The comments (sparse as they are) say that INDF0 is supposed to point to PORTA and INDF1 to LATA, but I don't know that nor do I see any evidence this is actually the case.  It's also not clear what CS_INPUT is supposed to be, and why it is relevant to your test anyway.

If you are having a problem reading a input pin, write a loop that just reads the pin and mirrors it to another pin.  That will probably work fine.  Then keep expanding that step by step until some incremental step exhibits the symptom.  Now you have a much better idea what might be wrong.  And no, it's not going to be the BTFSS instruction failing.

It would be good to look at the Vdd pin at the same time you see the glitches.  Maybe the 5V supply isn't as clean as you think.  Maybe something else is causing occasional glitches on the supply or the other lines.

Comment: Slightly aggressive answer there.

Comment: I'm not looking to blame anything, clearly the setup is at fault. What I was hoping for were some ideas. I have already done all of the things you suggested, with no success.

Comment: @Rocket: If you want people to take you seriously, don't start out blaming the hardware as the title of your question does.

Comment: @Rocket: If you have already done all the things I suggested, then what were the results?  At what point did it start failing as you made a simple loop more complicated?

Comment: It did not work at any point.

Comment: How would you have phrased it?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet Olin's answers might be harsh sometimes, but always constructive

Comment: Olin's answers are great :) No offense Olin, but I laugh when you are so aggressive in the answers, no offense. One question; you have been in PICs for a long time I guess, what do you think the odds of there is a faulty PIC (or uC) out of the factory are?

Comment: @abdullah: Nowadays faulting chips coming out of the factory is very rare, whether Microchip PICs or other chips from any other reputable vendor.  Every chip is carefully tested.  For you to receive a bad chip, something would have to damage it after the final test.  Handling techniques and packaging are designed to prevent that, although of course no process is ever perfect.  If you do have a bad chip, it's far more likely that your circuit or manufacturing or other handling killed it than it was DOA.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is caused by some kind of partial failure of the chip. I swapped out the part, and the problem has gone away.

Turns out it was the hardware after all ;)

Comment: This problem is happening again on other chips. Still trying to find the answer.